# How to review the inconsistently labelled messages in Gmail conversations?

Tags: gmail-labels

It appears that individual emails within a conversation can be inconsistently labelled - I think this arises when using GMail on Android where individual messages can be labelled.

This problem arose when I searched for "mykeyword -label:mylabel" and conversations showed up which WERE ALREADY labelled with mylabel.  SOME of the messages WITHIN the conversation were not labelled with mylabel, so the entire conversation showed up.

Is there a way to review all the label variation within a conversation and conform them?  Right now, I have to unlabel and relabel the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of Gmail's default "conversations" feature. If you turn off the conversations function in gmail and then do your search it will not show the parts of the conversation already labeled.

Comment: Actually, the standard conversation view does not fix the labeling issue. See this [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234882/need-help-optimizing-a-google-apps-script-that-labels-emails) thread for some resources on scripts that you can run to fix it. Also see [here](http://jamesmurty.com/2008/03/13/gmail-labelling-search-bug/) for more discussion.